# Kinds of stars and local plant life

Tags: creature-design, flora, stars, colors

I know how the color of a planet's flora is affected by the light from its sun. But my problem is I keep getting things confused. Does anyone know of a resource that lays it all out in a chart? I'm sure many readers here could benefit.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. On Earth, we all have the same sun, but plants with many different leaf colors, are you asking for a chart of phyto-pigments, or about photosynthesizing compounds and what color they are? Can you clarify.

Comment: We have a sample size of one, and the plants on Earth reflect a light (green) in which a lot of the energy reaches the surface. So -- we don't know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do different star types produce plants with different properties?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11562/do-different-star-types-produce-plants-with-different-properties)

Comment: this question has been asked many times, please search for your question before posting.

Comment: Because plant has chlorophyll which absorbs red light easily and reflects green light, red light has much longer frequency and less likely to be scatter in the atmosphere (btw our sun emits a broad spectrum of light but thankfully Earth is caught right in the Goldilocks zone so there you go ;D

Comment: *"I know how the color of a planet's flora is affected by the light from its sun":* maybe yes, maybe no. Do you have an example of planet where the color of the flora is affected by the light from its sun? The color of the leaves of Earth's flora is certainly an evolutionary accident, not linked to the spectrum of light coming from the Sun. And anyway, "color" is a sensation which exists only in the mind. It is not a physical quantity, it does not exist in nature. The "colors" of the leaves of Earth's plants are a *double* accident: the intrinsic properties of the leveas, *and* the human mind.

Answer (score 1):

Artifexian and Worldbuilding Notes released a video overview of plant, sky, and sun combinations: https://youtu.be/L9MNC45Jr6Q

And a Google Doc calculator to output plant colours according to those variables: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/1YhSapw5xSUli1H321JSM2JqMfbmuzqwJp5Iba6DxuWs/htmlview#

Screencaps of the calculator:
[image: Calculator for atmospheric composition]
[image: Calculator for plant colour based on stellar variables]